# Is $X_n$ a Markov chain?

Tags: stochastic-processes, markov-chains

A fair coin is tossed repeatedly with results $Y_0, Y_1,....$ that are $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ each. For $n \ge 1$ let $X_n = Y_n+Y_{n-1}$ be the number of $1$'s in the $(n-1)$th and $n$th tosses. Is $X_n$ a Markov chain?

---

Let $Y_n=1$ if it's head or else $Y_n=0$. 
Then $X_n = Y_n +Y_{n+1}$ can take value of $0,1,2$. 
I would like to proof that $X_n$ is a Markov chain by using the definition.

\begin{align*}
& P(X_{n+1}=i_{n+1} | X{n}=i_n, X_{n-1}=i_{n-1},...,X_0=i_0) \\
& = P(X_{n+1}=i_n | X{n}=i_n)\\ & = P(X_{n+1}=Y_{n+1}+Y_{n}|X_n=Y_n+Y_{n-1} )\\
& = P(Y_{n+1}+Y_{n} = i_n | Y_n+Y_{n-1} =i_{n-1} )\\
& = P(Y_{n+1}+Y_{n} = i_n |Y_n+Y_{n-1} =i_{n-1} , Y_{n-1}+Y_{n-2} =i_{n-2} ,...,Y_1+Y_0=i_0)
\end{align*}

It seem like an easy question but I have a hard time doing it.Not sure if it's correct. Can anyone give me a hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there's  a typo in your question, should be $X_n = Y_n + Y_{n-1}$ in the second time you typed it(the index in the the 2nd $Y$ is decremented in the first and incremented in the second).

$X_n$ is not Markov. Consider this:

$P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = 1) = P(Y_3 = 1)P(Y_1 = 0) = .25$

$P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = 1, X_1 = 0) = P(Y_3 = 1) = 0.5$

Comment: in the case $P(X_3 = 2 | X_2 = 1)$ why is that equivalent to $P(Y_3 = 1)P(Y_1 = 0)$? Could you also do $P(Y_3 = 1)P(Y_1 = 1)$?